# Does an Artinian ring have only finitely many maximal left ideals?

Tags: ring-theory

I read here: http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00J4

If R is Artinian then R has only finitely many maximal ideals. 
I'm pretty that holds only for commutative artinian rings.

Because I found here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55701/are-there-only-finite-many-maximal-left-ideals-for-a-left-artinian-ring

The answer is no for non-commutative rings.

So I will use the example there.

Let $R=M_2(\mathbb{Q})$. Why is this Artinian? Is it finite dimensional over $\mathbb{Q}$ so is Artinian right?

What are its maximal left ideals?

Comment: There is a theorem characterizing left and right ideals in $M_n(K)$ for any field $K$. Namely, a left ideal is a set of the form $L_W = \{A \mid W \subseteq \ker A\}$ for some subspace $W$ of $K^n$. A right ideal is a set of the form $R_W = \{A \mid \operatorname{im} A \subseteq W\}$ for some subspace $W$ of $K^n$. I don't have a reference for this, unfortunately.